# Limiting set of scaled natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers, natural-numbers

This may be a non-standard question, and possibly irrelevant to the participants. Nevertheless, after reading the first chapter of Terence Tao's book on measure theory, I ended up thinking about what would be the limiting set of a set $\frac{\mathbb{N}}{N}\cap [1, 2]$, (where N is a positive integer) and then let $N \to \infty$.

i.e.   $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{N}}{N}\cap [1, 2]$ where $\frac{\mathbb{N}}{N} = \{\frac{n}{N}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. At first superficial glance it seems like the limiting set is $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,2]$, but maybe I'm missing some subtle details.

**Edited - added image:**
This question was motivated by Tao's definition of a length of a Jordan measurable interval:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi7i8.png)

Comment: Do you have a particular definition of "limiting set" you're working with here? According to the straightforward one I can think of offhand, that sequence of sets has no limit at all.

Comment: Hi @Henning Makholm, this is what I'm trying to establish, (1) whether it makes sense to talk about the limit of a set, and if yes, then (2) what it would look like.

Comment: The subsequence $\frac1{N!}\mathbb N\cap[1,2]$ indeed has $\mathbb Q\cap[1,2]$ as its limit, whereas the different subsequence $\frac1{N!+1}\mathbb N\cap[1,2]$ has a limit of $\varnothing$.

Comment: I'm confused why it would be $\emptyset$, as the number of elements should increase to $\infty$ as we are squeezing an increasing number of points into a [1, 2] interval. The greatest lower bound being 1 and the least upper bound being 2?

Comment: x @Alex: Sure the _number_ of elements increases, but each individual point is _absent_ from all the sets $\frac1{N!+1}\mathbb N$ from some step onwards. Similarly the sets $B_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n\}$ contain an increasing number of naturals but nevertheless have empty limit.

Comment: @Henning Makholm oh yes I see, did not notice the $N$ factorial. However, for the case $N$ is not clear to me. As I said it was a non-standard question, and I just wanted to understand in more detail Tao's definition of a length for (Jordan measurable ) interval which I have now included in the question. Many thanks for a valuable input!

Comment: It is possible to formulate a notion of limit of sets, by requiring the sequence of indicator functions on the sets (i.e. the maps $x \mapsto 1\ if\ x \in A,\ 0\ if\ x\not \in A$) to converge (in some sense) to some indicator function. If you consider pointwise topology, a sequence of sets $(A_n)_n$ converges to $A$ if and only if, for any $x$, $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in A_n$ for sufficiently large $n$ and $x \not \in A \Rightarrow x \not \in A_n$ for sufficiently large $n$.